# Java Thread Output data to Collection getting wrong results

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a small program for testing java's Thread.
The problem is that I cannot get results as I predicted: 100 records every time.
I got random number of records. and after I remove the comment of this line:

//System.out.println(name + " Completed.");

I got 100 records as predicted every time.
In other words, I add a System.out.println(), everything works perfect.
Is that the java's bug or something I didn't noticed?

MyThread.java

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

  @Override
  public void run() {

    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      if (i == 10) {
        //System.out.println(name + " Completed.");
        TestThread.al.add(name);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

TestThread.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestThread {

  public static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<MyThread> mt = new ArrayList<MyThread>();

    //set
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      mt.add(new MyThread());
      mt.get(i).setName("Worker " + (i + 1));
    }

    //start
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      mt.get(i).start();
    }

    //end
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mt.get(i).join();
    }

    //result
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("Rank " + (i+1) + " : " + al.get(i));
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I am getting all 100 records with commented line and without commented line, only difference is order is random when you uncomment line.

Comment: after using Vector, I got 100 records and random order with or without the line. then the thread test was successful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the ArrayList is not `thread-safe`, maybe there exist a case: the two `threads` write data to the same `positon` of the arrayList ,you can use Vector instead for it is thread-safe.

for more information about `thread-safe` come [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html)

Comment: Thanks. After using Vector, I got 100 records every time.

Answer (score 0):

cainiaofei has answered it, but wanted to add few more points:

Your `ArrayList` object **`al` is causing the problem as it is being accessed(reads/writes) by many threads concurrently**.

You need to know the below basic points:

Whenever many threads concurrently access an object ensure that you need to use thread-safe classes like `Collections.synchronizedList()` (prefer this) or `Vector`.

If you need thread safety for primitive types, you can make use of JDK's atomic package, for which you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks. now I know more about synchronized methods.